# "Duplicate" hot answers in tag-wiki

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

I was just editing [codereview-se](/questions/tagged/codereview-se) and stumbled upon the tag-wiki to verify my edits.

What I saw there made me chuckle slightly, well see for yourselves:

[image: Duplicate hot answers]

I know there were multiple answers to the duplicate questions. One of them I answered myself. Now If I read that for the first time it looks just like there were answers in the hot-list **twice** and I doubt that.

To better show that these are different answers I'd like to suggest adding the answer-score to the links there. (Similar to "related questions" / "linked questions")